# How to manipulate and return tf.Variable using a for loop over tf.data.Dataset inside function decorated with @tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a function containing a for loop over a TensorFlow Dataset that assigns a new value to a TensorFlow Variable in each iteration. The Variable should also be returned as output of the function. With eager execution enabled, there are no issues, however, in graph mode, some unexpected things seem to happen. Consider the following simple dummy code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.increment = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0, 1, 2])

    @tf.function
    def fn1(self):
        self.var.assign(0)
        for _ in tf.range(3):
            self.var.assign(self.var+self.increment)
            tf.print(self.var)
        tf.print(self.var)
        return self.var

    @tf.function
    def fn2(self):
        self.var.assign(0)
        for _ in self.dataset:
            self.var.assign(self.var+self.increment)
            tf.print(self.var)
        tf.print(self.var)
        return self.var

    @tf.function
    def fn3(self):
        self.var.assign(0)
        y = self.var
        for _ in self.dataset:
            self.var.assign(self.var+self.increment)
            y = self.var
            tf.print(y)
        tf.print(y)
        return y

    @tf.function
    def fn4(self):
        var = 0.0
        for _ in self.dataset:
            var += 1.0
            tf.print(var)
        tf.print(var)
        return var
```

`test.fn1()`, `test.fn3()` and `test.fn4()` all return the following (desired) output:

```
1
2
3
3
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>
```

However, `test.fn2()` behaves differently:

```
1
2
3
0
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>
```

Interestingly, after execution of `test.fn2`, `test.var` does seem to contain the correct value:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>
```

I am not sure why `test.fn2` fails. Clearly, it is doing some things correctly (as `test.var` contains the correct value after execution of the function), but it does not deliver the correct result. Can you help me understand what causes this code to fail?

The behavior described above occurs when using TensorFlow 2.1.0 for Python 3.6 on CentOS 7.

Comment: Hi webs, kindly provide TensorFlow version and other necessary details.

Comment: The behavior described in the question occurs when using TensorFlow 2.1.0 for Python 3.6 on CentOS 7. I will add these important details to the question.

Also, after some extra testing I found out that when using TensorFlow 1.15.0 instead, the first three functions fail at the very first line with the following exception:

`TypeError: In op 'Assign', input types ([tf.float32, tf.float32]) are not compatible with expected types ([tf.float32_ref, tf.float32])`.

I'm not sure this has something to do with the issue at hand, but thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this on **TensorFlow 2.1.0** reproduces your scenario.

Which prints `1 2 3 0` for `test.fn2()`, but you should also consider that when you print `self.var` in `test.fn3()` it will also show you `self.var = 0` during the function call.

**Modified** **fn3( )**:

```
    @tf.function
    def fn3(self):
        self.var.assign(0)
        y = self.var
        for _ in self.dataset:
            self.var.assign(self.var+self.increment)
            y = self.var
            tf.print(y)
        tf.print(self.var)  # Inspect self.var value
        tf.print(y)
        return y
```

**Output:**

```
# Executed in Tensorflow 2.1.0
# test.fn3()
1
2
3
0  << self.var
3
```

This is already fixed If you execute this in **Tensorflow 2.2.0-rc2**.
The output will be your desired outcome even when printing it during graph execution.

To quickly simulate this you could use **Google Colab** and use `%tensorflow_version 2.x` to get the **latest available version** for **Tensorflow**.

**Output:**

```
# Executed in Tensorflow 2.2.0-rc2
Function 1
1
2
3
3
Function 2
1
2
3
3
Function 3
1
2
3
3 << Value of self.var in test.fn3()
3
Function 4
1
2
3
3
```

You could check more about the changes in the **latest Tensorflow Updates** in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases).